# Converses to a commonplace proposition about binomial distributions

Tags: probability-distributions

I suspect I'll post my own answer to this question shortly, but it may be of interest to see what answers others post.

A theorem found in Feller's famous book and elsewhere says that if $X,Y$ are independent random variables and $X+Y$ is normally distributed, then $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed.

Is there a similar result for binomial distributions?  I.e. can we show that
$$
\begin{align}
& \text{if }X_1,X_2\text{ are independent and } X_1+X_2\sim\operatorname{Binomial}(n,p) \\
& \text{then for some }n_1,n_2,\quad X_i\sim\operatorname{Binomial}(n_i,p)\text{ for }i=1,2\text{ ?}
\end{align}
$$

**PS ADDED LATER: Could we assume throughout that random variables considered here take values in $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$.**

In fact, I **suspect** we can get a stronger statement:
$$
\begin{align}
& \text{if } X_1+X_2\sim\operatorname{Binomial}(n,p)\text{ then $X_1,X_2$ are independent} \\
& \text{and then for some }n_1,n_2,\quad X_i\sim\operatorname{Binomial}(n_i,p)\text{ for }i=1,2.
\end{align}
$$
Is that also true?

Both of these are **converses** of a proposition found in every textbook.

Comment: You cannot conclude independence of components of a sum, if you only know properties of the sum. For example given $X=X_1+X_2$, you cannot rule out $X_1=X_2=\frac{1}{2}X$ unless you assume independence of $X_1$ and $X_2$ *a priori*.

Comment: Better example perhaps: $X_1=X_2+\epsilon$ with $|\epsilon|\leq1$.

Comment: For your weaker statement, consider $X_1 = -1$ always gives this constant negative value (hence not a binomial distribution), and $X_2=1\sim B(1,1)$. The result $X_1+X_2\sim B(n,0)\sim B(0,p)$ is binomial, but its component may not be binomial ($X_1$), or may not share the same $p$ (X_2).

Comment: Consider I. $X$ and $Y$ are independent,  II. $X$ and $Y$ are normal, and III. $X+Y$ is normal. The standard proposition is that if I and II hold, then so does III, while Cramer's theorem which you quote (cited in Feller) says that if I and III hold, then so does II.  But clearly when III holds, II might hold but I need not hold (even if II does) since $X$ and $Y$ could be jointly normal correlated random variables too.  Now replace _normal_ by _binomial._ You are asking whether III implies both I and II. Could you provide some intuition why such a result might be true?

Comment: @DilipSarwate : I think I can provide a reason why someone might mistakenly think that's true.  But a reason why it might be true is another matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counterexample:

Consider $X_1$ uniform on $\{0,2\}$. Assume that, if $X_1=0$ then $X_2$ is uniform on $\{0,1\}$, and that, if $X_1=2$ then $X_2$ is uniform on $\{0,-1\}$.

(In other words, $(X_1,X_2)$ is uniform on the set $\{(0,0),(0,1),(2,-1),(2,0)\}$.)

Then $X_1+X_2$ is Bin$(2,\frac12)$ but $(X_1,X_2)$ is not independent.

Comment: A bit rushed but I'll look at this.  If the propositions are wrong, then are there some fairly weak additional hypotheses that make them right?

Comment: Since the conditional distribution of $X_2$ given $X_1$ is not the same for both values of $X_1$, can we still claim that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent?

Comment: @DilipSarwate No we cannot (claim this), and we did not since this is a counterexample to the so-called "stronger statement".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Any thoughts on the weaker statement? Can the characteristic function $(1-p+p e^{it})^n$ of a binomial $(n,p)$ random variable be factored into the characteristic functions of two random variables in any way other than $(1-p+p e^{it})^m\cdot (1-p+p e^{it})^{n-m}$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate The support of the terms of the sum should be, up to opposite translations, subsets of the nonnegative integers, hence we are asking if the polynomial $(px+1−p)^n$ can be the product of two polynomials that are not suitable powers of $px+1−p$. It cannot, qed.